Banana Cake Pop IDE length query issue
I use Banana Cake Pop IDE in my project (.net 7 ASP.API) for a long time with no issues.
But recently I've found very strange behavior - if request is too long, IDE will send to API back-end previous request, ignoring current query (in my case it's mutation) which is in IDE reflected.
Don't know concrete max length, but the reason is in length for sure. Once I'll make query shorten   - IDE will send updated one.
I use HotChocolate.AspNetCore 11.3.8 version.
If use the same query thru Postman - no issue.
Mutation with issue has more 5.4K symbols. With length about 4K - no issue.
Expected solution is to have an error about long query, or do not have such limitation at all (like in Postman).
Current behavior causes to bad issues, as far as IDE just sends previous query one more time with no specific warning or error.

What version of BananaCakePop are you using?

HotChocolate.AspNetCore 11.3.8 which includes BananaCakePop
